# Invite command in discord.py (Invite user to server by ID)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

As the title suggests, I want to add a command to my bot which would DM someone an invite to the server. Using a static link which is permanent is not an option because I want the command to be available across different servers.

This is what I have so far:

```
@BSL.command(pass_context = True)
async def invite(ctx, userToInvite):
        inviteLinq = await BSL.create_invite(destination = ctx.message.channel, xkcd = True, max_uses = 1)
        await BSL.send_message(userToInvite, inviteLinq)
```

However, I get an error `InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, User, or Object. Received str`. I understand that this is due to the fact that the messages in discord are saved as strings.

Is there a way to make it so that you can specify the ID of an user and they receive the invite link in DMs?

Comment: Could you try something like `print(type(ctx.message.channel))` before the `create_invite`?  `ctx.message.channel` should be a `Channel` object, not a string.

Comment: Sure, however, I think the problem is in the `await BSL.send_message(userToInvite, inviteLinq)` bit as it also contains a destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `userToInvite` is a string, but it should be a `User` object.  You should use [`Server.get_member_named`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.get_member_named) to get the `Member` object from the server. Something like

```
@BSL.command(pass_context = True)
async def invite(ctx, userToInvite):
        inviteLinq = await BSL.create_invite(destination = ctx.message.channel, xkcd = True, max_uses = 1)
        target_member = await ctx.message.server.get_member_named(userToInvite)
        await BSL.send_message(target_member, inviteLinq)
```

EDIT:

If you're inviting a user to this server using their id, you should instead try

```
@BSL.command(pass_context = True)
async def invite(ctx, userToInvite):
        inviteLinq = await BSL.create_invite(destination = ctx.message.server, xkcd = True, max_uses = 1)
        target_user = await BSL.get_user_info(userToInvite)
        await BSL.send_message(target_member, inviteLinq)
```

Comment: Sooo, it does not work. :( When I specify the nickname or the ID of the user, I get `Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, User, or Object. Received NoneType`. Also, I think that instead of `member` we should use `user` because the user is only to be invited, they aren't part of the server yet. I'm not sure however so I will wait for your reply first.

Comment: So you're trying to issue an invite to a user not on the server, from a command issued on the server? How are you specifying the target user?

Comment: By the user ID,  something like `269913216678195896`. For example, I talk to my friend in DMs, I copy his ID and paste it in the command. The bot then DMs him the invite link.

Comment: @user9123 see my edit.  You can use the `Client.get_user_info` coroutine for this.

Comment: I used the exact code from your edit but I got the error: `NotFound: NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Channel`. Any idea what the problem is? I think that for some reason it is trying to send the message to a channel not the user.

Comment: @user9123 Do you know which line the error is on? (It should tell you.)  I would either expect either `create_invite` (It couldn't find the user for some reason) or `send_message` (It couldn't create a private chat with that user to send the invite.  Maybe a permissions issue, but then I'd expect a 403 Forbidden)

Comment: `File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BSL.py", line 128, in invite
    inviteLinq = await BSL.create_invite(destination = ctx.message.server, xkcd = True, max_uses = 1)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2628, in create_invite
    data = yield from self.http.create_invite(destination.id, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 198, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Channel`

Comment: This is the most interesting part of the traceback. It looks like it's an error with the invite link command. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try removing the `xkcd` argument? That might be effecting something. Try creating the invite to `ctx.message.channel` instead.  Make sure that the bot has invite privileges. You might want to try reauthorizing it with those privileges to make sure, by creating a new OAuth link.

Comment: Turns out that I had to change the destination like you said. Everything works fine. [Here](https://snag.gy/U50BQO.jpg) is a screenshot if you wish to see the end result. Thank you sooo much for your help. Answer accepted!